# Unable to connect bluetooth keyboard (org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled)

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 23.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10  from 23.04 on my Lenovo P14s, and since then I am unable to connect my Bluetooth keyboard (Logitech K850). Everything works as expected up until the system asks to input a validation code. It is displayed for only half a second before being closed.
Using the `bluetoothctl` tool, I have the following log within less than a second:

```
[bluetooth]# pair <MAC address>
Attempting to pair with <MAC address>
[CHG] Device <MAC address> Connected: yes
[agent] Passkey: XXXXXX
[CHG] Device <MAC address> Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

I also tried to trust the keyboard before connecting it, without success:

```
[bluetooth]# trust <MAC address>
[CHG] Device <MAC address> Trusted: yes
Changing <MAC address> trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect <MAC address>
Attempting to connect to <MAC address>
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed le-connection-abort-by-local
```

Bluetooth is working fine, as my mouse (Logitech M720) and headset are working just fine.

Comment: Your keyboard has a unifying receiver, which should provide a more reliable connection in general. Can't you connect your keyboard using that?

Comment: It indeed works after installing solaar to handle the unifying reciever. I would still prefer not to have to use this additionnal device it possible